# how can i use derby database with the build .jar file?

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans, derby

i'm using java with the derby database.

When i start the connection of the "jdbc:derby"-database in netbeans and run my code,the program shows up and everything works fine.

By opening the built ".jar"-file, the program just shows up and close immediately right after that.

So how do i have to configurate netbeans that the build .jar file work with the derby database?

(i thought derby was file based, so that the build process must generate something like a database file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your program crashes during the execution of your jar file, there is probably an exception. If it works in Netbeans, the exception is probably caused by the path to your derby.jar.

The first thing I can think of is that you have incluced the derby.jar in your application using a relative path and you have not moved the derby.jar inside your project library.

Try to do the following:

1: copy the derby.jar to a directory (for example /lib) in your project folder

2: include the jar using relative path from your /lib folder

**EDIT:**

Here is a sample code of how to create your database when it is newly created:
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");

```
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:\\Users\\TheReaver\\MyDB;create=true;user=thereaver;password=12345");
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT ID, NAME FROM APP.TABLE1");
        try
        {
            ResultSet res = st.executeQuery();
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            //if table not found, then create all tables
            st.executeQuery("CREATE TABLE TABLE1(ID int, NAME varchar(20)))");
            //execute all statements that create your database
            //or execute an sql file that stores all your queries
        }
```

Comment: i have included the derbyclient.jar(soo it is in the /lib folder of dist) but i don't know how to include my database in netbeans.is there a way how to include my database in the project properties? (under services in netbeans there is the Java DB -> mydatabase)

Comment: ok i figured out that the .jar file runs,when netbeans is open and i have started a connection with my database. but the enduser will have no netbeans and will not start a database connection...this is the problem (EDIT : I even have included the JAVA DB DRIVER as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26312063/export-project-with-derby-database-in-netbeans

Comment: why is there no mydatabese.db or a similar filetype in the dist folder?

Comment: The path to your database is set when you create the Connection object. If the database does not exist there, it will create it by default. Here is a sample code:Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:\\Users\\TheReaver\\MyDB;create=true;user=thereaver;password=12345");

Comment: ok,but how can i create the tables then? (i create them with netbeans not with sql syntax)

Comment: i mean how can i import the structure of my database (and maybe some data) from Services->JAVA DB -> mydatabase ?

Comment: You need to execute the create statements in the beginning of your program - if the database does not exist you have to create all tables using queries. I`ll edit my answer so u can see a demo code

Comment: thanks a lot :) one last question: how can i use an relative path?

Comment: The path in my example in the answer is absolute - it starts from the root of the file system. The relative path starts from the directory of your project.